# Spring BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping maps pattern url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-mapping

I have this particular query regarding BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping in Spring. Part of my dispatcher-servlet.xml looks like below -

```
<bean id="beanNameUrl" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

<bean name="/start.htm" class="controller.StartController"/>
<bean name="/login.htm" class="controller.LoginController"/>
<bean name="/company.htm" class="controller.CompanyController"/>
<bean name="/client.htm" class="controller.ClientController"/>
<bean name="/paginate.htm" class="controller.PaginateController"/>
<bean name="/detail_view.htm" class="controller.DetailViewController"/>
<bean name="/edit_view.htm" class="controller.EditViewController"/>
<bean name="/create_view.htm" class="controller.CreateViewController"/>
<bean name="/building.htm" class="controller.BuildingController"/>
<bean name="/tower.htm" class="controller.TowerController"/>
<bean name="/floor.htm" class="controller.FloorController"/>
<bean name="/space.htm" class="controller.SpaceController"/>
<bean name="/contract.htm" class="controller.ContractController"/>
<bean name="/space_package.htm" class="controller.SpacePackageController"/>
<bean name="/charge_head.htm" class="controller.ChargeHeadController"/>
<bean name="/search_view.htm" class="controller.SearchViewController"/>
```

Now, what happens is, whenever am trying to get to the space_package.htm, it always ends up in space.htm and to top it all, whatever I type in place of the * in  `http://host:port/app_name/space*.htm`, it always end up in space.htm !!

Please advise how should I resolve this and where am I going worng.

Appreciate your help...:)

Comment: Can you try putting /space_package.htm before /space.htm?

Comment: What does SpacePackageController do?

Answer (score 0):

The URLs are named incorrectly. According to web standard, An URL can not contain special character (like "_"), so that `/space_package.html` is invalid. You may want to try `/spacePackage.html` instead.

For further understanding, you can refer the document in [this link](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).